# Gradle build error in android application

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-import

Previously my app was running ok.(in android-studio) But suddenly, it says that

> "No resource found for attribute 'viewportwidth' in Package android ".

I could not resolve this error. why this is happening.

Can anyone help me out of this ?

Comment: Clean your project, use gradle sync and compile again

Answer (score 1):

I think you have typo, it should be

```
viewportWidth // with capital W
```

instead of

```
viewportwidth
```